# Go (Golang) efficient logic processing in a chat system

Tags: go, architecture, chat

In order to build a messaging app, I have followed this example : https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat

This consists of a Hub, running in a single goroutine in the program, which binds together the Clients (the intermediary between the socket and the Hub).

In this example, each Client (connected user/websocket) runs 2 goroutines : one for reading messages, one for writing.
So we end up with a single goroutine for the Hub, and many goroutines for all the connected users in the app (2 per each user)

But this is for an app which all it does is broadcast all the messages to all the connected users. Since my goal is to build a messaging app (similar in functionality to whatsapp, messenger and the likes, where a user has private conversations with a friend(s)), I need to adjust this design accordingly.

So, I've split this into two layers :

1. Connection layer - Hub + Client. This layer is responsible for keeping the connections with the clients (plus everything that it entails - reading/writing messages, encoding/decoding, etc.)
2. Business Logic layer - the "core" / the logic itself. Meaning - communicating with the DBs, be it an SQL or Cache like Redis, in order to insert messages, finding participants in each conversation, etc.

**Challenges** :

Since the Logic layer has more resource-consuming operations (reading and writing to DBs, finding out which users belong in the conversation so it would know to tell the hub which users in its Clients mapping to send the message to), I'm having hard time to decide where that should lie and how the two layers should interact/communicate with each other?

Because the Hub is central to the app and has 1 goroutines to handle all traffic, I'm assuming it cannot just call "processMessage" in the Service layer, and wait for its response. Otherwise we can potentially reach a state where we have many pending messages and users will start receiving messages with great delay. (Please do correct me if I'm wrong here)

**Ideas so far + problems** :

So what I though of doing, is to have another Service goroutine for the app, just like the Hub, which the Hub will run once it's initialized, and then the Hub could send a message for it to process using a channel between them. Then, once the Service is done, it sends back to the Hub's channel something like "hey dear Hub, send this message I gave you, to users: 1, 2, 3".

But here I think I have another problem - since Hub and Service are in different packages, it means I need to have a cyclic dependency, because Hub knows about Service (it forwards a received message for it to process), and Service knows about the Hub (it tells the Hub what message to send to which users after it's done processing the received message from hub).

So it seems that each option has either a performance issue or an architectural/design issue. Or both.
Since I'm not an expert in Go, that would be really helpful to learn how to handle this kind of case both efficiently(performance-wise) and correct (design-wise).

Comment: You may want to consider posting this question somewhere more appropriate, like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ for example. And maybe revisit https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I don't have an answer for the question, but I do have some advice:  Don't get locked into the design of the chat example.  A read goroutine is required, but don't assume that the hub and write goroutines are needed.